# WP8 App signing does not always work

Tags: windows-phone-8, code-signing, xap

We are developing WP8 apps and having trouble with the applications that we signed. We tried almost every combination of SignTool XapSignTool etc... We installed the AETs in the mobile devices and actually this signing was working before. Either with VS 2013 or Windows 8.1 something has changed. The signing is still successful but the device does not recognize the key as a valid key. This is the latest command that we are using:

Edit: The error is: There is a problem with this company app. Contact your company's support person for help.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XapSignTool\xapsigntool.exe sign /SignTool "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86" /v /f Path\to.pfx Path\to.xap
I tried all combinations of different versions of windows kits signtool etc... I greatly appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ensure the machine that is signing the app has both the intermediate and root certificates from Symantec installed to the Local Machine store before running the XAP signing tool.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I noticed that Windows complains no certificates were found that met all given criteria. However, this shouldnt be an issue since the same key works on Pro 8.1

Comment: @Steffan San I'm not sure what you mean, but if you're developing an enterprise application and you obtained an enterprise signing certificate from Symantec, you were issued a Symantec root authority and intermediate authority with your corporate ID cert that are required in order to sign packages yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to sign your app? When publishing apps to Windows Phone Store you don't need to sign it, you just need to to build it in Release mode and upload the created XAP file, nothing more.

Comment: If the OP is installing Application Enrollment Tokens (AETs) on mobile devices, this is indicative of enrollment for enterprise application distribution, which sidesteps the Windows Phone Store entirely and uses direct distribution or more likely a Mobile Device Manager to deploy the application. These applications must be self-signed and optimized using the XAP signing tool.